# NordVPN blocking local file sharing traffic (tried whitelisting internal IP)

Tags: vpn, file-sharing

I'm trying to set up my Linux server to always be connected through NordVPN while still allowing for local network file sharing. I've read that whitelisting the internal IP (ex. 192.168.1.0/24) has done the trick for others, but it's not helping me for whatever reason.

Here are my NordVPN settings:

```
Technology: OPENVPN
Protocol: UDP
Firewall: enabled
Kill Switch: disabled
CyberSec: disabled
Obfuscate: disabled
Notify: disabled
Auto-connect: enabled
IPv6: disabled
DNS: disabled
Whitelisted subnets:
    192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: Read `man ip ip-route` and add a route for your LAN addresses to your router/switch/hub.

Comment: Hello. You may want to ask the Nord VPN people if you can even do this. I use ExpressVPN and it does not allow this kind of config.

Answer (score 0):

I have Nord running on my media server 24/7.  My problem was Nord denying connections after a day or two.  I whitelisted the Plex Media Server port in addition to the subnet.  I used "nordvpn whitelist add port 32400".  Time will tell.